# ffmpeg drawtext + colorspectrum - background partly transparent only

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I am currently working with the `drawtext`/`alphamerge` filters to have the text coloured with `colorspectrum` on a transparent background. While I have been trying many options, the closest I managed to get is a partial transparent background, which is just not good enough. The colours are slightly visible on most backgrounds I will use this on. [image: colorspectrum is bleeding through]

How can I make the `colorspectrum` disappear completely, except in the text?

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -loglevel error -stats -filter_complex \
   "color=black@0:1920x1080:r=60,trim=end=10[bg]; \
   colorspectrum=size=1920x2:r=60,crop=iw:1,scale=iw:1080,scroll=horizontal=-0.0025[gradient]; \
   color=black@0:s=1920x1080:r=60,drawtext=text='Lorem ipsum':fontsize=60:fontcolor=white:x=w-t*w/5:y=1006[text]; \
   [gradient][text]alphamerge, [bg]overlay=shortest=1" \
-c:v libvpx-vp9 -an -movflags faststart stream-fans.webm
```